# $_FILES['tmp_name'] llega vacío

Tags: php, ajax, post

Tengo un formulario donde envío una imagen con ajax pero en el otro archivo php solo me recibe el nombre de la imagen y no el tmp_name

ESTE ES EL FORM

```
<form method="POST" id="formRT" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <div class="mb-3">
         <label for="formFile" class="form-label">Banner</label>
         <input class="form-control" type="file" id="formFile" name="archivo" style="max-width:400px">
     </div>
     <button type="button" id="btnRE" class="btn btn-primary w-100" name="btnAgregaEquipo" style="max-width:400px">Registrar</button>
</form>
```

Este es mi ajax

```
$("#btnRE").click(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "registrarTorneo.php",
                method: 'POST',
                contentType: false,
                cache: false,
                processData: false,
                data: new FormData($('#formRT')[0]),
                success: function(res) {
                    alert(res);
                }
            });
        });
```

Este es el php que recibe la imagen y que solo recibe el nombre de la imagen

```
$nombreB=$_FILES['archivo']['name'];
$nombreBTmp=$_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'];
$ruta="".$nombreB."     ".$nombreBannerTmp;
if($nombreB!="" && $nombreBTmp!=""){
    move_uploaded_file($nombreTmp,$ruta);
    echo "Success";
}
echo $ruta;
```

Imprimo `$ruta` pero solo me muestra el nombre de la imagen, aunado a eso me muestra el error

> Undefined variable $nombreBannerTmp

Comment: Qué te sale en la consol.a del navegador? Qué te sale en los logs de PHP?

Answer (score 0):

Veo algunas cosas que no me cuadran.

```
$nombreB=$_FILES['archivo']['name'];
$nombreBTmp=$_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'];
$ruta="".$nombreB."     ".$nombreBannerTmp; // De donde sale esta última variable ????
if($nombreB!="" && $nombreBTmp!=""){
    move_uploaded_file($nombreTmp,$ruta);
    echo "Success";
}
echo $ruta;
```

Siempre depura tu código (ya me cansé de repetirlo), mira que llega, que se envía, mira todo antes de procesar.

```
print_r($_POST);
```